# Can one capture the properties of Turing machine using only function definitions?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

I am trying to capture the definition of Turing machines as abstractly as possible (without any implementation). Will a definition like this do the trick?

---

Definition [Turing machine]:

Let $\mathbb{L}$ be the set of all finite sentences with finite alphabet $\Sigma$ including the empty sentence $\varnothing$. As an example, the sentences of the binary alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1 \}$ are the binary sentences.

A Turing machine is a partial function $\operatorname{TM}: \mathbb{L} \to \mathbb{L}$:

$$
  \operatorname{TM}(d) = r
$$

iff $\operatorname{TM}(d)$ halts.

---

Does this definition capture all Turing machines and only Turing machines?

Comment: If $TM$ doesn't halt on input $d$ (with whatever unspecified initial location in that string), how is there anything on the right of the equals sign at the end?

Comment: @EricTowers The definition works from the other way... if r is there for a given d you must find a TM such that the definition is realized. If there exists a TM for all possible permutation of this function, then the definition is that of Turing machines in general.

Comment: That is entirely **not** what $TM:\Bbb{L} \rightarrow \Bbb{L}$ means.  When you write "$TM(d) = {}$" after that, you must provide an element of $L$ on the right of the equals sign.  It is understood that partial functions do not evaluate at all inputs -- but whatever values appear in the brace on the right must be elements of $L$.  (Of course, the conditions for choosing those values can be more elaborate.)

Comment: @EricTowers Wikipedia: "In mathematics, a partial function f from a set X to a set Y is a function from a subset S of X (possibly X itself) to Y. " Then, Example is given: $F:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$; implemented as $f(x,y)=x-y$ iff $x>y$. 
My claim: But this is the same as 
$$ 
f(x,y)=\begin{cases} x-y & x>y \\ \nexists & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Are you trying to capture *Turing machines* or *(partial) computable functions*? The former is discardable language if what you really care about is the latter (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function#Definition)).

Comment: I don't find your unsourced quotation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function and I don't find the bizarre notation you quote there.

Comment: However, I think @NoahSchweber is right.  Your commented "... you must find a TM ..." strongly indicates your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks for point the XY problem; I will train myself to avoid doing this.

Comment: @EricTowers Example is here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Subtraction_of_natural_numbers and quoted stated is the first sentence of the page.

Comment: There is no "$\not\exists$" anywhere on the page you link.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, The last is (my claim); saying iff x>y is equivalent to a piece-wise function, where the other piece is undefined. Do you agree or disagree? Two different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: 100% disagree, as already explained.  The only thing appearing on the right of that equals sign is elements of $\Bbb{L}$.  If you want to say that a particular case does not evaluate you do it **exactly** as it is done in the subsection you link: in prose.

Comment: @EricTowers check my edit.. better?

Comment: Much.  <!-- pad to 15 characters -->

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132209/discussion-between-anon21-and-eric-towers).

Answer (score 1):

There are more partial functions from $\mathbb{L}$ to $\mathbb{L}$ than there are Turing machines in the classical sense of the term. Specifically, there are at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ partial functions from $\mathbb{L}$ to $\mathbb{L}$ (this counts the number of mappings from binary sequences to the singleton sequences $\mathtt{0}$ and $\mathtt{1}$), but there are only $\aleph_0$ possible TMs (each TM can be written as a binary sequence).

Since your definition includes at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ items but there are only $\aleph_0$ Turing machines, your definition can't be capturing all and only the Turing machines.

An example of something not captured: pick any non-recursively-enumerable language (say, the language of all TMs that don't accept their own encodings). Then you can define a (total) function $f : \mathbb{L} \to \mathbb{L}$ as

$$f(d) = \begin{cases}
   \mathbb{0} & \text{if }d \text{ is the encoding of a TM that does not accept itself } \\
   \mathbb{1} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

No TM exists that (semi)-decides this set, but by your definition this object $f$ would be a Turing machine.

But more generally to your original question - can you capture Turing machines just using functions? - the answer is yes. The [$\mu$-recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function) are a family of recursively-defined (partial) functions that compute exactly the same set as Turing machines. For a slightly more general notion of what a "function" is, you could look to the [$\lambda$-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), which similarly captures the expressive power of Turing machines using a system based purely on recursive application of functions.

Comment: Hum... can I just add the restriction that $F:L \to L$ be a computable function (partial of L)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function, and talk about this generally irrespective of any implementation?

Comment: @Anon21 At that point I worry your definition becomes circular. To define what a "computable function" is you need some reference model of what "computable" means. That's often defined in terms of Turing machines, so if you said the function was computable when defining TMs you'd have a (nonterminating) recursive definition.